# How do I add a statement in javascript based on the current url?

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to check what url the user is on and compare it to a default value and then run a statement

Let's say my url is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, I'm trying to do this, and it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      if(document.location.href('/questions/ask') > 0)
  {
    [do this];
  }
```

Thanks for the help(noob question I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, you are missing the `indexOf` method.

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf('/questions/ask') > -1)
```

But I believe you should be going off of the window object, I think document is deprecated (but still works).

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('/questions/ask') > -1)
```

You also want to check to see if the index is greater than negative one because zero is technically a correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var loc = new String(window.location);
if(loc.match('/questions/ask')) {
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` gives you the whole url. You can also access other properties of location, like `protocol`, `pathname`, `hash`, `host`.

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/questions/ask')
```